# Avro RPC multiple Responders for one NettyServer

Tags: kotlin, netty, rpc, avro, idl

I'm studying Avro RPC and I'm trying to create a simple example to better understand it.

But I'm facing a difficulty: I can't run a server with more than one `Responder`, as the NettyServer constructor only allows me to use one:

```
public NettyServer(Responder responder, InetSocketAddress addr)
```

So, if I have more than one IDL, like this:

```
@namespace("foo.bar")
protocol FooProtocol {
    void foo();
}
```

---

```
@namespace("foo.bar")
protocol BarProtocol {
    void bar();
}
```

I'm not able to add both to my NettyServer (as in listening to the same port):

```
object FooProtocolImpl : FooProtocol {

    override fun foo(): Void? {return null}
}
object BarProtocolImpl : BarProtocol {
    override fun bar(): Void? {return null}
}
```

---

```
val server = NettyServer(SpecificResponder(FooProtocol.PROTOCOL, FooProtocolImpl), InnetSocketAddress(9090))
```

How to add BarProtocol to my server? How to make this NettyServer useful for both Protocols?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A post by Doug Cutting in [GrokBase](http://grokbase.com/t/avro/user/128e5qne9d/registering-multiple-classes-to-a-responder) states:

> A separate Responder is currently required for each protocol. If HTTP
>   is used, different ResponderServlet's can be configured so that
>   different protocols are run at different URLs. For NettyServer and
>   SaslSocketServer one must run different protocols on different ports.
>
> Note however that one can create a protocol that's the combination of
>   several other protocols and serve that. For example, with Java
>   reflection, if you have Java interface A that's one protocol and Java
>   interface B that's another then you can implement "interface C extends
>   A, B" and serve that protocol. Clients that speak either A, B or C
>   can then connect. A similar effect can be accomplished with Java's
>   specific compiler by importing various client protocols into the
>   server's protocol.
>
> http://avro.apache.org/docs/current/idl.html#imports

So an alternative is to create a `protocol` that "implements" all your protocols, such as:

```
@namespace("foo.bar")
protocol AllProtocols {
    import idl "foo.avdl"
    import idl "bar.avdl"
}
```

and creating your class that implements this protocol:

```
object AllProtocolsImpl : AllProtocols {
    override fun foo(): Void? {return null}
    override fun bar(): Void? {return null}
```

}

then creating your server that serves this protocol:

```
val server = NettyServer(SpecificResponder(AllProtocols.PROTOCOL, AllProtocolsImpl), InetSocketAddress(9090))
```

Any client requiring Foo or Bar may connect to this server and use its protocol.